# How to add autoprint function in an existing print dialog box

Tags: javascript, php, printing, keypress

I am having a hard time figuring out the printing of ticket queue automatically since in my generated code, it only appears a new window and a print dialog box, I use MS Edge browser here. I want to automatically print it after that dialog box appear, like you press and enter to print it. Please help, here's my Javascript thanks

```
<script>
function printLayout() {
    var _el = $('<div>')
    var _h = $('head').clone()
    var _p = $('#outprint').clone()
    _h.find('title').text("Queue Number - Print")
    _el.append(_h)
    _el.append(_p)
    var nw = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=700,height=500,top=75,left=200')
    nw.document.write(_el.html())
    nw.document.close()
    setTimeout(() => {
        nw.print()
        setTimeout(() => {
            nw.close()
            $('#uni_modal').modal('hide')
            window.location.href = '/queuing/kiosk/'
        }, 200);
    }, 500);
}

$(function() {
    printLayout();

})
```

Comment: It is not possible to force the browser to print without user intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Lol, I already figured it out. I used Google Chrome browser, I created a shortcut file and modified the properties in TARGET:

> "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk
> --kiosk-printing [url of the kiosk page]